# defining a path

Tags: php, zend-framework, path

I am setting up a Zend environment and cannot get the past this error.

This is the code:

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)). '../application');

set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/' 
                . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path()
                );
echo APPLICATION_PATH;

require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
```

This is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, you are missing a slash before the ../application:

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(FILE)). '/../application');

set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path() ); echo APPLICATION_PATH;
```

To provide more details, I think we'd need to know about the directory structure, where the index.php is, etc.

Comment: with the slashes I get this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)

Comment: none from me, you'll need someone with more knowledge of zend to help you out with that.  But at the very least, you should either update your question or create a new one with your new error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem on my own.  I realized that the controller folder was misspelled.  It looks like this error is usually caused when the appropriate file structure isn't there or if the controller file is misspelled.